# findKey() - recreating lodash library method

Tags: javascript

I've got a problem with a CodeCademy task. I am to re-create the `findKey` lodash library method. Here there are the steps of how to do it, but I got stuck, especially at point 5.

1. Add a method to our `_` object called `findKey`.
2. Add two parameters to this method: `object` and `predicate`. We will
   name our `predicate` function parameter `predicate` since this is the
   name used in the Lodash documentation.
3. Within the method, use a `for ... in` loop to iterate through each key
   in `object`.
4. Within the loop, create a variable called `value` and set it equal to
   the value at the current key in `object`.
5. Still within the loop, create another variable called
   `predicateReturnValue` and set it equal to the result of calling
   `predicate` with `value`.
6. Finally, still within the loop, use an `if` statement to check
   if `predicateReturnValue` is truthy. If it is, return the current key
   from the method.
7. Outside of the loop, return `undefined` to address all cases where no
   truthy values were returned from `predicate`.

This is my code that doesn't work:

```
findKey(object, predicate) {
  for (let key in object) {
    let value = object[key];
    let predicateReturnValue = predicate(value);
    if (predicateReturnValue === 'true') {
      return value;
    };
  };
  return undefined;
}
```

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the key after the truty check of the call of `predicate`.

```js
function findKey(object, predicate) {
    for (let key in object) {
        let value = object[key];
        let predicateReturnValue = predicate(value); 
        if (predicateReturnValue) {                   // just take the value
            return key;                               // return key
        }
    }
}

const
    isStrictEqual = a => b => a === b,
    object = { a: 'foo', b: 'bar', c: 'baz' }
    
console.log(findKey(object, isStrictEqual('bar')));
console.log(findKey(object, isStrictEqual('cat')));
```

Comment: Ohhhh THX A LOT! :) It passed the test! THX <3

Comment: @Nina Scolz why did you remove your answer? It was really interesting. I am waiting for an answer from you.

Comment: @anonymous, may answer addressed a diffretn problem, as i was reading the problem, to get all travel stations in an array. but you just needed (as you later clarifies), the unique values of the array/objects ...

Comment: why don't you post another best answer?